# How do you select the inside vertices of an object faster?

Tags: mesh, vertices, edges, faces, selection-tools

I've been seeing some tutorials and they all make two mouse clicks and somehow manage to get a clean selection of the inside vertices with no use of Alt or the B key which is what I usually have to do...asking for a friend.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you could simply select the bottom central vertex then <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> to automatically select more. I guess it's the trick you're talking about. But <kbd>B</kbd> or lasso select tools would also quickly do the job.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could select the element in the center(face or vertex) and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> multiple times to grow selection:

[image]

You can also <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click to select some loop and then use "Select Loop Inner-Region" function that you can find in the search menu(<kbd>Space</kbd>/<kbd>F3</kbd>(2.8)) or in the Select menu in the 3D View header:

[image]